# ExpressionEngine Index page repeats its' code over and over until all pages' contents have loaded

Tags: structure, expressionengine, repeat

Been working on wrapping my head around expression engine now. And I'm using the Structure add-on as well. This is my first attempt of building my own template.

The problem I'm having is on the index page when you initially land on the site. It will repeat the entire html over and over until its' loaded every pages' content. It only does this on the index page. If you click on any other page it works as its supposed to.

Heres my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{exp:channel:entries channel="pages"}
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    {!--    add="filename|filename2"    --}
    {embed="Pages/styles"}
    {embed="Pages/scripts"}
    <title>{title}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="/" id="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" /></a>
        <nav>
            {exp:structure:nav css_id="none" start_from="/" show_depth="2"}{/exp:structure:nav}
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <nav>
            {exp:structure:breadcrumb inc_home="no" here_as_title="yes"}{/exp:structure:breadcrumb}
        </nav>
        {if structure:child_ids != '' OR structure:parent:entry_id != '0'}
        <aside>
            {exp:structure:nav css_id="none" show_depth="2" start_from="/{segment_1}" show_overview="yes" rename_overview="{structure:top:title}"}{/exp:structure:nav}
        </aside>
        {/if}
        <article>

            <h1>{title}</h1>
            {page_contents}
        </article>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <nav>
            {exp:structure:nav css_id="none" start_from="/" max_depth="1"}{/exp:structure:nav}
        </nav>
        <address>
            <p>1234 Address St<br />
                City Name, STATE 12345<br />
                Phonee: 123 456 7890<br />
                <a href="#">Email Us</a></p>
        </address>
    </footer>
</body>
{/exp:channel:entries}
</html>
```

And here is the link to the site: (no styling, just building and testing for now) http://www.oneoffs.co

Comment: Hi Noah!  Most ExpressionEngine questions are better asked on ExpressionEngine StackExchange, unless they involve development (such as developing extensions in PHP). http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ah, thanks. I didn't realize there was one. I will repost there.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the prettiest solution but you could simply add entry_id to the loop which would limit it to only the homepage.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="pages" entry_id="1"}
..
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

or

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="pages" {if segment_1 == ''}entry_id="1"{/if}}
..
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

...which only adds the entry_id if you're on your homepage (assumption that segment_1 is blank).